# I want to animate the scroll behavior in android using a button

Tags: android, scroll, android-widget, overlay, android-appwidget

I want to click a button which help me scroll any screen on the android. The button will be presented as a widget which will be overlay on the top of all the apps. Is there any API or method available in Android to do so? If not, how can it be achieved?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything so far. I just want the generalized idea on how to do that. I'm looking for any APIs or methods, etc which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your whole layout inside a ScrollView and move that ScrollView on the button's click using the fullScroll method.

your_scroll_view.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
your_scroll_view.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);

Comment: I want to control scrolling on **all the apps** of the phone on every screen.